# The visa date of birth is different from the passport date of birth

Tags: visas, usa, passports

My spouse's U.S. visa date of birth is different from her passport date of birth.

Would she be to travel and what date of birth should be on the ticket?

Comment: You should go to the US consulate and get a corrected visa.

Comment: The date on the ticket, on the passport and on the visa should be the day she was born.  And nothing else.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of passport or what kind of visa or what kind of airline. It needs to be fixed pronto.  Those data items need to sync up and it is a matter of urgent priority.

Answer (score 7):

Her visa is invalid - if it doesn't match the passport that it is in then it is not valid.

It is possible that you will be able to enter the US with the incorrect visa, but it's also possible that you will have issues, up to or including not being allowed to board the flight to the US.

You should return to the consulate it was obtained from, and bring it to their attention.  I have had a similar mistake made on a US visa (incorrect LCA expiry date), and it was fixed in a matter of minutes, the old visa was cancelled, and a new visa was put in the passport.